# Buscar usuario con LDAP, usando otras credenciales

Tags: php, ldap

Buen día.

Después de mucho googlear me veo en la necesidad de postear mi duda, ya que no encuentro la solución a mi caso especifico.

Les cuento que estoy utilizando la función ldap_bind() de PHP para loguear a mis usuarios con Active Directory. Lo complicado es que necesito utilizar a un cierto usuario que tiene las credenciales correctas para poder realizar las consultas.

A continuación mi código, con algunas modificaciones de datos, obviamente:

```
<?php
//Usuario y pass a través del método POST
$usuario_login = $_POST['nombre_usuario'];
$pass_login = $_POST['pass_usuario'];

//Usuario con credenciales para hacer consultas en AD
$usuario_LDAP = 'Admin';
$contrasena_LDAP = 'AdmindPass';

$servidor_LDAP = "100.10.100.1";
$servidor_dominio = "midominio.com.mx";
$ldap_dn = "dc=midominio,dc=com,dc=mx";
$puertoldap = 389;

$ldaprdn = trim($usuario_LDAP ).'@'.servidor_dominio ;
$usuarioBuscar = $usuario_login.'@'.servidor_dominio ;

$ldapconn = ldap_connect($servidor_LDAP ,$puertoldap);
ldap_set_option($ldapconn, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION,3);
ldap_set_option($ldapconn, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS,0);

$ldapbind = ldap_bind($ldapconn, $ldaprdn, $contrasena_LDAP);

if ($ldapbind){
     $filter = '(sAMAccountName='.$usuario_login.')';
     $attributes = array("name", "samaccountname");
     $result = ldap_search($ldapconn, $ldap_dn, $filter, $attributes);
     $entries = ldap_get_entries($ldapconn, $result);
     $userDN = $entries[0]["name"][0];
     echo ('<p style="color:green;">El DN del usuario: '.$userDN.'</p>');

      //Aquí he intentado la segunda búsqueda, con Usuario@midominio.com.mx y $userDN
     $ldapBindUser = ldap_bind($ldapconn, $usuarioBuscar, $pass_login);
     //$ldapBindUser = ldap_bind($ldapconn, $userDN, $pass_login);

     if($ldapBindUser){
          echo ("<p style='color: green;'>Usuario autentificado!!!</p>");
          ldap_unbind($ldapconn); // Clean up after ourselves.
     } else {
                echo ("<p style='color: red;'>Usuario no autentificado :(</p>");
       }
?>
```

El primer usuario si lo encuentra, pero ya el segundo no, me aparece un **Warning: ldap_bind(): Unable to bind to server: Invalid credentials in...**

También he intentado las búsquedas con los siguientes formatos:

```
//$usuarioBuscar = $usuario_login.'@midominio.com.mx;
$usuarioBuscar = 'midominio.com.mx\\'.$usuario_login;
$usuarioBuscar = 'CN='.$usuario_login.',DC=midominio,DC=com,DC=mx';
```

Se que no es un tema común, pero agradecería cualquier consejo o comentario que me puedan dar...

Comment: A mi tu primer script me funciona, solamente he añadido una llave de cierre al final del mismo, faltaba una llave para cerrar el primer IF que has hecho. Más allá de esto ahora me encuentro yo con otro problema distinto. En el navegador me da un error: HTTP ERROR 500
Si lo pruebo por consola todo perfecto.

Answer (score 0):

Vengo a cerrar la pregunta. Después de mucho buscar, no encontré mejor opción que utilizar una librería de Laravel: encontré dos opciones [LdapRecord](https://ldaprecord.com/docs/quickstart/) y [Adldap2](https://adldap2.github.io/Adldap2/#/). Ambas son muy similares, yo opté por utilizar está última.

Al final mi archivo quedó así:

```
<?php
//Agrega la librería ADLDAP2
require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';
//Crea un objeto
$ad = new Adldap\Adldap();
//Usuario con credenciales para hacer consultas en AD
$usuario_LDAP = 'Admin';
$contrasena_LDAP = 'AdmindPass';

//Crea el arreglo con los datos de configuración
$config = [
    'hosts'            => ['100.10.100.1'],
    'base_dn'          => 'dc=midominio,dc=com,dc=mx',
    'username'         => $usuario_LDAP,
    'password'         => $contrasena_LDAP,
    'port'             => 389,
];

$servidor_dominio = "midominio.com.mx";

$connectionName = 'my-connection';

$ad->addProvider($config);

$ad->addProvider($config, $connectionName);

//Usuario y pass a través del método POST. El usuario que voy a buscar
$usuario_login = $_POST['nombre_usuario'];
$pass_login = $_POST['pass_usuario'];
try {
    //Se realiza la conexión con el usuario admin
    $provider = $ad->connect($connectionName, $usuario_LDAP, $contrasena_LDAP);
    // Great, we're connected!
        $username = $usuario_login.'@'.$servidor_dominio;
        $password = $pass_login;

        try {
            //Se realiza la búsqueda del usuario
            if ($provider->auth()->attempt($username, $password, $bindAsUser = true)) {
                session_start();
                $_SESSION["User"] = $usuario_login;
                echo"<script>window.location.href='menu_principal.php'; </script>";
            } else {
                // Failed.
                echo '<br>Error al identificarse';
            }
        } catch (Adldap\Auth\UsernameRequiredException $e) {
            // The user didn't supply a username.
            echo '<br>No se encuentra el Usuario';
        } catch (Adldap\Auth\PasswordRequiredException $e) {
            // The user didn't supply a password.
            echo '<br>La Contraseña No Es Correcta';
        }


} catch (Adldap\Auth\BindException $e) {
    // Failed to connect.
    echo '<br>Error al conectarse al Active Directory';
}
```

Espero que le sirva a alguien más.

Saludos y gracias por su atención.